# SilverLight DataGrid: Copy & paste

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, datagrid

1. Is there a way that I can select a bunch of rows or cells from a SilverLight DataGrid and Copy them for pasting into e.g. excel?

The DataGrid doesn't seem to have this functionality built in!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight 4 is great, Ctrl-A a datagrid, copy and paste it into Excel.

You can even customize what gets copied using ClipboardContentBinding, which is quite useful if you are using a TemplateColumn.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out this link - seems fairly useful
http://weblogs.asp.net/manishdalal/archive/2008/11/12/cross-browser-copy-and-paste-in-datagrid-with-excel-support-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight uses a vector rendering system.  The text is not the same as text in Notepad- it's being rendered as a vector image.  You can't highlight text in Silverlight or Flash.

If you're writing the app, offer a "download Excel file" button that redirects to an Excel file generator.

Comment: Silverlight 3 adds a "FileSaveDialog" control that can be used for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do this programmatically? If so, then you are out of luck with Silverlight 3. Silverlight 4 is supposed to add this functionality.