# Copy datagrid with headers

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

How to copy silverlight datagrid with headers? When im use Ctrl+C on datagrid, the content of datagrid is copied but without headers name...

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post possibly has your answer: [SilverLight DataGrid: Copy & paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304318/silverlight-datagrid-copy-paste)

And this may also help, depending on what you are trying to do: [Silverlight DataGrid: Export to excel or csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304322/silverlight-datagrid-export-to-excel-or-csv)

I haven't marked this question as a possible duplicate because there is no marked answer on the closest matched question.